# Uniform convergence of series $ \frac{x^{n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}$converge uniformly on interval $[0,1)$?

I've tried to use tail convergence test, but I've got stuck. How should I proceed? Or Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: What do you think the limit of the sum would be as $x \to 1$?

Comment: it diverges is there something i can do with it?

Comment: Well, if you a finite number of terms can that diverge? The limit is $x \mapsto \ln { 1\over 1-x}$, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Prove by contradiction. If the series is uniformly convergent then there exists $N$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{N_2}\frac {x^{n}} n <\epsilon$ whenever $x \in [0,1)$ and $N_2 >N_1>N$. Let $x$ increase to $1$ in this to see that $\sum\limits_{k=N_1}^{N_2}\frac 1 n\leq \epsilon$ whenever $N_2 >N_1>N$. But this is false since $\sum \frac  1n$ is divergent.